Product of 2 locally uniformly convex (L.U.C) Banach Spaces is L.U.C.
I'm trying to prove in a "simple way" that if $X$ and $Y$ are both L.U.C. Banach spaces, then $X\times Y$ with the norm $||(x,y)||=(||x||^2 + ||y||^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ $($for all $x\in X$ and for all $y\in Y)$ is also L.U.C.
We say that a Banach space $X$ is L.U.C. if for any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $S_X$ such that $||x_n+x||\rightarrow 2$ for some $x\in S_X,$ we have that $||x_n-x||\rightarrow0$.
I'm aware of the general case with infinite p-sums but the proof is very long and complicated and I only need this particular case. Thank you :)

I'm sorry but what is LUC?

Locally uniformly convex (L.U.C.) means that if a sequence ${x_n}\in X$ verifies that $||x_n+x||\rightarrow 2$ for some $x\in X$ then $||x_n-x||\rightarrow 0$.

Did you mean to assume $\Vert x_n\Vert=1$?

Yes, I assume $||x_n||=||x||=1$, sorry if I didn't specify before.
